# Solution to a system of equations

Tags: systems-of-equations, cubics, symmetric-polynomials

Find all triples $(x,y,z)$ of real numbers
        satisfying the following system:
        $$
    \begin{cases}
            (x+1)(x^2+1) = y^3+1\\
            (y+1)(y^2+1) = z^3+1\\
            (z+1)(z^2+1) = x^3+1
    \end{cases}
    $$
I tried adding and multiplying the three equations and I still can't see how to proceed further!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- If $x>0$ then $$ x^2+1> x^2-x+1$$ and $y,z>0$ so $$ y^2+1> y^2-y+1$$ and  $$ z^2+1> z^2-z+1$$ and thus $$ (x^2+1)(y^2+1)(z^2+1)> (x^2-x+1)(y^2-y+1)(z^2-z+1)$$ which is a contradiction since (notice that $x,y,z\ne -1)$  $$ (x^2+1)(y^2+1)(z^2+1)= (x^2-x+1)(y^2-y+1)(z^2-z+1)\;\;\;\;(*)$$
  We get $(*)$ if we multiply all given equations and cancel equation we get with $x+1$, $y+1$ and $z+1$.
- If $x=0$ then $y=z=0$.
- If $x<0$ then $y^3 = x(x^2+x+1)<0$ so $y<0$ and $z<0$ 
  Now if $x=-1$ then $y=z=-1$. So suppose $x\ne -1$ then $y\ne-1$ and $z\ne -1$ so we have again $(*)$. But now we have also: $$ x^2+1< x^2-x+1$$ and $$ y^2+1< y^2-y+1$$ and  $$ z^2+1<z^2-z+1$$ and thus $$ (x^2+1)(y^2+1)(z^2+1)< (x^2-x+1)(y^2-y+1)(z^2-z+1)$$ which is a contradiction with $(*)$ again.

So $x=y=z=0$ or $x=y=z=-1$ are the only solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Calling

$$
y = f(x)\\
z = f(y)\\
x = f(z)
$$

we have

$$
y = f^3(y)\\
z = f^3(z)\\
x = f^3(x)
$$

Then $x,y,z$ are fixed points of $f^3$ but the only fixed points are $\{-1,0\}$

hence $x=y=z=-1$ and $x = y = z = 0$

NOTE

$$
f(x) = \sqrt[3]{(x+1)(x^2+1)-1}
$$